# CustomTkinter Label showing wrong time

Tags: python, tkinter, customtkinter

I wrote an application with the libraries Tkinter and CustomTkinter to make a world clock app.

When you first open the file, you'll see multiple buttons that, when clicked, show the times of the respective place.

[Here is an image of the menu.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xJBDU.png)

Now the problem is that all of these buttons end up showing the time for "Los Angeles, USA". It used to work fine, but since I made some refactoring changes, it's been like this.

```
import tkinter as tk
import customtkinter as ctk
from datetime import datetime
import pytz

# ------------ Preparation ------------
# Create the window
root = ctk.CTk()
root.iconbitmap("img\\icon.ico")  # custom defined icon
root.title("World Clock")
root.geometry("600x400")
root.configure(bg=("#ebf0f5", "#19191a"))
ctk.set_default_color_theme("theme.json")
ctk.set_appearance_mode("dark")

# Lists to better assort values
locations = ["Berlin, Germany", "Chennai, India", "London, UK", "New York, USA", "Tokyo, Japan", "Los Angeles, USA"]
timezones = ['Europe/Berlin', 'Asia/Kolkata', 'Europe/London', 'America/New_York', 'Asia/Tokyo', 'America/Los_Angeles']

# Import the photos necessary for the buttons / switch
images = [tk.PhotoImage(file='img\\germany.png'), tk.PhotoImage(file='img\\india.png'), 
            tk.PhotoImage(file='img\\uk.png'), tk.PhotoImage(file='img\\usa.png'), 
            tk.PhotoImage(file='img\\japan.png'), tk.PhotoImage(file='img\\usa.png')]

img = tk.PhotoImage(file='img\\theme.png')
switch_var = ctk.StringVar(value="on")
# -----------------------------------------------------


def menu():
    # Make the title
    title = ctk.CTkLabel(root, text="World Clock", text_font=("Audiowide", 25), padx=10, pady=7.5, 
                            borderwidth=1.5, text_color=('#008080','#017878'))
    title.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.125, anchor='center')

    # Switch for light/dark mode
    icon = ctk.CTkLabel(root, image=img)
    icon.place(relx=0.84, rely=0.082)
    theme_switch = ctk.CTkSwitch(root, height=25, width=45, command=set_mode, text=None, 
                                    variable=switch_var, onvalue="on", offvalue="off")
    theme_switch.place(relx= 0.84, rely= 0.095)
    
    # Make the buttons
    for i in range(6):
        button = ctk.CTkButton(root, image=images[i], text=locations[i], text_color=('#277575', '#369191'), 
                                command=lambda: display_time(i))
        buttons.append(button)
    
    # Place all the buttons
    buttons[0].place(relx=0.23, rely=0.35, anchor='center') # Berlin, Germany
    buttons[1].place(relx=0.77, rely=0.35, anchor='center') # Chennai, India
    buttons[2].place(relx=0.23, rely=0.6, anchor='center') # London, UK
    buttons[3].place(relx=0.77, rely=0.6, anchor='center') # New York, USA
    buttons[4].place(relx=0.23, rely=0.85, anchor='center') # Tokyo, Japan
    buttons[5].place(relx=0.77, rely=0.85, anchor='center') # Los Angeles, USA

def set_mode():
    # switch between light/dark mode
    if switch_var.get() == 'on':
        ctk.set_appearance_mode("dark")
    else:
        ctk.set_appearance_mode("light")

def clear_frame():
    for widget in root.winfo_children():
        widget.destroy()

def display_time(num):
    clear_frame()
    root.geometry("400x200")  # change window size for appropriate fit
    location = locations[num]  # set location
    display_time.tz = pytz.timezone(timezones[num])  # set timezone

    # Prepare the labels
    text = ctk.CTkLabel(root, text=location, text_font=("Arial", 16), padx=10, pady=7.5, 
                    borderwidth=3)
    text.place(relx=0.5, y=20, anchor='center')

    display_time.time_label = ctk.CTkLabel(root, text_font=("Arial", 42))
    display_time.time_label.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor='center')
    display_time.date_label = ctk.CTkLabel(root, text_font=("Arial", 12))
    display_time.date_label.place(relx=0.5, y=175, anchor='center')

    update()

def update():
    time = datetime.now(display_time.tz).strftime("%H:%M:%S")
    date = datetime.now(display_time.tz).strftime(f"%A, %d.%m.%Y") 

    display_time.time_label.configure(text=time)
    display_time.date_label.configure(text=date)
    root.after(1000, update)  # update every second

# ---------- Run ----------
buttons = []
menu()

root.mainloop()
```

Where did I make a mistake?

As I am a beginner in programming, I would also request for some feedback on my code structure.

I thank you in advance.

Comment: You meant to create the command parameter like this: `command=lambda i=i: display_time(i)`. Otherwise the `i` parameter is taken the mean the last value for `i`.

Comment: Apologies for the late response, but it worked. I thank you a lot. I wasn't aware there was a similar question and had not even thought of searching that way, so once again thanks for that.